# Total Commander profile migration

Tags: migration, total-commander

How do I migrate totalcmd profile from one machine to another? Settings are stored in registry (unfortunately).
I don't need exact copy, but the more settings survive, the better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most of the TC profile is actually stored in two INI files: `wincmd.ini` and `wcx_ftp.ini`.

To find those, check the [Total Commander wiki](http://www.ghisler.ch/wiki/index.php/Finding_the_paths_of_Total_Commander_files#Finding_the_TC_main_config_file). There are 6 possible places to look; I've usually found the files by checking these registry keys:

> 4) Look for the registry key value:
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Ghisler\Total Commander\IniFileName
>
> If it's not empty, this is the result. Overwise go to next step.
>
> 5) Look for the registry key value:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Ghisler\Total Commander\IniFileName

Usually, the other INI file will be in the same folder.

Also, your `wincmd.key` (license key file) would likely be in the program's directory; if not, check wincmd.ini for `KeyPath=`, this is the location of your license key file.

Answer (score 0):

You can find both files in user profile folder also. You can check where this setting is stored in TC itself.

1- Click on **Help** at the top-right of the Total Commander.
2- Click on **About Total Commander**.
3- Now you will find **INI-Files:** tag.
4- Here under the tag all the path of setting files are defined.

Answer (score -4):

I know it's quite illegal if I talk about pirate version here. But you can find the portable Total commander at portableappz.xx ( find yourself ). If you have license key, you can replace exsisted one in the data folder. You can move it to everywhere :)

Comment: It's not piracy if you *own* the license key... but "portable Total Commander" doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Total Commander can be made portable anyway.  The option is there in the installer, and the settings can be kept in the program folder.  There is no need to use a portable launcher with Total Commander.

Comment: @grawity: It can solve the problem if you download the pack I mention above, then put your data file in there. Everything will work fluently.
@paranoid: Some of settings are stored in registry

Comment: The question *is* how to put the "data file" in "there".